# Odd behaviour of file_get_contents() in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, file-get-contents

I have used file_get_contents() to download files with CakePHP in the past and it works well.

However, I am working on a new site and when I use file_get_contents() to download either csv or zip files (have not tried others), I get something odd being tagged to the start of the file created on the client machine.

Using notepad++ to look it seems as if:

`LF
TabTabTabSpaceSpaceLF
TabTabTabSpaceSpace`

Is being added.  AND the next line of text seems to be indented (but that may just be how notepad++ interprets the characters above - or there may be another character not being displayed by notepad++ !)

I have looked and looked at my controller and view to see if something is being added but I really can't see anything untoward.

Has anyone seen any behaviour like this before, and if so, did you find out what was causing it?

(I fully appreciate this may just be bad coding by me, but I want to keep this a short question rather than include loads of code..)

Many thanks

Paul

Here are the code snippets that I believe to be pertinent:

in config/routes.php

```
Router::parseExtensions('csv');
Router::parseExtensions('pdf');
Router::parseExtensions('zip');
```

in AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {
//...

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Acl',
        'RequestHandler',
        'Paginator'
    );
```

In controller for pertinent model:

```
public function add_download($pass){
//create a record in the database table VisitDownloads
//recording who is downloading what and when

$this->loadModel('JournalArticleDataset');
$this->VisitDownload->create();
$this->VisitDownload->set(array('visit_id' => $this->Session->read('Visit.id'),
'journal_article_dataset_id' => $this->request->params['pass'][0],
'download_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
//record is saved to database
$this->VisitDownload->save();
//build filename string to identify fully the resource being downloaded,
// then download
$filename = $this->JournalArticleDataset->get_filename($this->request->params['pass'][0]);
$filestring = "/files/".$filename;
if(substr($filename,-3)=='csv'){
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". substr($filename,0,strlen($filename)-4) ."_".date('Y-m-d_H:i:s').".".substr($filename,-3)."\"");
}
if(substr($filename,-3)=='zip'){
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". substr($filename,0,strlen($filename)-4) ."_".date('Y-m-d_H:i:s').".".substr($filename,-3)."\"");
}


$filecontent = file_get_contents($filestring);
echo $filecontent;
exit();
}
```

and then the link to this action in a view:

```
echo "<table class='rightmove'>";
foreach($journalArticle['JournalArticleDataset'] as $Datasets) :
$filestring = "/srv/www/actc.lshtm.ac.uk/public/openaccess/webroot/files/" . $Datasets['dataset_resource_name'];
$extension = pathinfo($Datasets['dataset_resource_name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

?>
 <tr>
            <td><?php 

            $filesize = human_filesize(filesize($filestring), $decimals = 2);
            echo $this->Html->image("/fileicons/".$extension .".png", array('url'=>array('controller'=>'VisitDownloads', 'action'=>'add_download',$Datasets['id'])));
            echo "\r\n<small>(". $filesize .")</small>" ;
            ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Datasets['dataset_resource_description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Datasets['dataset_resource_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Datasets['licence_type']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
endforeach;
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is causing the issue?

Comment: Okay, I have put the relevant (I think!) bits of code up.  I hope this helps.